# Can I detect that an administrator is logged on in a Shopify template?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm doing some customisation work to a Shopify template which involves triggering a redirect when the visitor is from a certain country.

However I don't want the redirect to trigger if the visitor is logged in as administrator.

Here is a (simplified) version of the javascript I'm using for the redirect:

```
//Access geo-location API
jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(location) {
  //If country code is "NZ" for New Zealand then redirect to another URL
  if( location.country_code == "NZ"){
    window.location = "http://www.example.com"
  }
});
```

Is there any way - either using the "Liquid" templating system, or Javascript to detect if the visitor is logged in as administrator?

Comment: Hi @Qantas94Heavy - they can still log in by appending "/admin" to the shop URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that works. The admin bar is stored in an iframe with the id: **#admin_bar_iframe**

If the visitor is logged in as an admin the width of #admin_bar_iframe is set to 100% under **receiveABMessage(event)** - which is set in the **<head>** . If the visitor is not logged in as admin the width of #admin_bar_iframe is set to 34px.

So by checking the width of #admin_bar_iframe I can detect whether the visitor is logged in as admin or not:

```
if(jQuery('#admin_bar_iframe').width() > 100){
          //Admin bar exists - do nothing
```

Comment: Looks like Shopify has changed things behind the scenes - this code no longer works. I've just tried it on a couple of demo stores and the `#admin_bar_iframe` does **not** exist for customers who aren't logged in. Could you check and update the answer if you see the same thing? (Can just do `jQuery("#admin_bar_iframe").length`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the shop is being rendered inside an iframe? Seems that would do the trick.